# Playstation Plus requiring a credit card to redeem card?

Tags: ps3, playstation-plus

I had a Playstation Plus card I got free from a friend with an Xbox. I entered the redeem code in and it said that a credit card is required. One of my friends said you need someone to go on your profile with a credit card, or use some credit card nearby and active plus then credit card then remove it, is that true?

Comment: Maybe it depends on region? In the UK, it's certainly not the case.

Comment: definitely not true in the US.  I buy PSN cards off amazon and add it to my account which does NOT have a CC attached since I don't trust sony with that info after their whole fiasco where they got hacked..

Comment: Is it a PSN card though because you mentioned xbox? What does it say on the card?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a 30-day trial (that comes with some  games now, definitely God of War: Ascension), rather than a 3/12 month card, then it's likely that they want you to enter your credit card details, so that when the trial runs out, your subscription will automatically take over.

The way around this is as your friend suggests, enter the credit card details, and then immediately go back into the 'PlayStation Network' > 'Account Management' > 'Transaction Management' > 'Services List' > 'PlayStation Plus' and remove the subscription.

This way you should be able to get the 30 day trial, and the credit card will not be charged once it expires.

Comment: +1 I can confirm this answer is correct. I just bought a 12 month membership and didn't need to enter any credit card information.

Answer (score -3):

It's true. I contacted Sony and they told me that there's no way to activate Plus without a credit card.

Comment: This is not true. To redeem a regular PS Plus code or wallet top-up you don't need to enter any payment information. The only exception are trials, as the other answer explains.